# Use value of text field in same HTML file

Tags: html, django, forms, bootstrap-4

I want to use the value of input text of name='t0' in the same HTML file.

Here is the code -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Insert Account</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="{% url 'account_select' %}" method="GET">
        <div class="text-center">
            Id: <input type="text" name="t0"><br>
            <div class="one">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="b1" value="Select">Select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

I want to use the value inserted in

```
<input type="text" name="t0">
```

in place of "HERE"

```
<form action="{% url 'account_select' "HERE" %}" method="GET">
```

Value has to be used in same HTML file because it will be directed to the the link.

Comment: You will need to use Javascript to append the value to the url before submitting(or constantly change the url as the value changes

Comment: @Mugoma can you please tell how to do it

Comment: I have posted an answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Insert Account</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form action="{% url 'account_select' %}" method="GET" id="myform">
        <div class="text-center">
            Id: <input type="text" name="t0" oninput="changeFormUrl(this)"><br>
            <div class="one">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-primary" name="b1" value="Select"
                    >Select</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
        const formUnappendedUrl = "{% url 'account_select' %}";
        function changeFormUrl(ele) {
            myform.action = formUnappendedUrl +'/'+ String(ele.value)
            //You may need to do your own validation on when value is empty
        }
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mugoma. It really helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Since you placed django in this question you have to create a model then from this model create a form then place it in your html file with a view function request.

Here is an example:

models.py

```
from django.db import models

class AccountSelect(model.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_lenght=50)

     def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

Migrate the model to create the table and add the form (you will need to create this file inside the app you want to create the form):

forms.py

```
from .models import AccountSelect
from django import forms

class AccountSelectForm(forms.ModelForm):
    """model to select accounts """
    class Meta:
        model = AccountSelect
        fields = ('name')
```

views.py

```
def account(request):

    if request.method == "POST":
        # call the form that will be used
        account_select_form = AccountSelectForm(request.POST)

         if account_select_form.is_valid():
             account_select = account_select_form.save(commit=False)
             account_select.save()
 
    # if a GET (or any other method) we'll create a blank form
    else:
        account_select_form = AccountSelectForm()

    return render(request, 'account_select.html'{'account_select':account_select})
```

Your template:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Insert Account</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
              {{ account_select_form | as_bootstrap }}
              {% csrf_token %}
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>
          </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and I am an amateur in Django. Can you suggest any other simple method ?